# How to read an attachment from jira and save using Rest Api

Tags: rest, jira

I have used attachment id to get the attachment details using rest api it executed and fetched a document from rest api but how shall i read this attachment and save in physical folder no matter of whether the attachment it is zip file pdf nor a document ?

```
    public Attachment GetAttachment(string attachmentId)
    {
        var request = new RestRequest()
        {
            Method = Method.GET,
            Resource = ResourceUrls.AttachmentById(attachmentId),
            RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json
        };

        return Execute<Attachment>(request, HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
public class Attachment
{
    public string self { get; set; }
    public string filename { get; set; }
    public Author author { get; set; }
    public string created { get; set; }
    public int size { get; set; }
    public string mimeType { get; set; }
    public string content { get; set; }
    public string thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

But how to read an attachment?

Answer (score 0):

getContent() and then base64 decode the returned string, I believe. The content type is set based on the name (extension) of the attachment when it was uploaded and can be used to determine what kind of data is in the decoded attachment content.

Comment: How to get the content of attachment a sample illustrating that ? Content property i get the url as "jira/secure/attachment/39532/1.doc" if i use in browser it prompts for save of that document.